# Can I somehow observe, which javascript events are fired? (active debug tool)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, debugging

When I'm in a complex website such as Facebook and write a comment and push Enter there is an event fired that starts everything. Can I somehow observe which events are fired and when (and eventually somehow trace/step them)?

So in general, I'm looking for a tool capable debugging a website in this way. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using devtools of Google Chrome, there is an Event Listeners tab that could help. See the attached picture.[image]
There, I have selected the "Post your answer" button of this very question and as you can see, the EventListeners tab shows that there is at least an onSubmit event listener attached.

Comment: Also under the "Sources" tab, you see what events take place, methods used, what scripts are being intiated, etc.

Answer (score -1):

One of the debugging tool that i am using and works well for me is firebug in mozila.

you can read about firebug [Here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)

With fire bug you can notice everything like webpage is making how much ajax call, which script is binned with which element. even you can also easily debug the css and design elements. firebug will help you more to debug the website on browser.